# Varnish returns MISS after successful HIT

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager, varnish

My application uses Varnish 3.0.2. I am facing a weird problem here. Some of the times the pages are served from Varnish with a `HIT`. But immediately after it returns `MISS`.

I was under the impression that once it gets served from the cache, it will continue to do so until the `TTL` expires. Am I wrong in understanding that?

Here are the two response headers for both the scenario:

**HIT**

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: Apache/2.4.16 (Unix) mod_auth_kerb/5.4 PHP/5.3.29
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.29
X-Drupal-Cache: MISS
Content-Language: en
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Encoding: gzip
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
cache-control: max-age=86400, public
X-Cookie-Debug: Request cookie: 
X-Request-URL: /org/31633421?unit=31633421
Content-Length: 11986
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Date: Wed, 24 Apr 2019 14:26:43 GMT
X-Varnish: 330015711 330015651
Via: 1.1 varnish
Connection: keep-alive
X-Varnish-Cache: HIT
X-Varnish-Cache-Hits: 1
X-Varnish-Age: 188
X-Varnish-Leg: 128.87.225.172
X-Varnish-Cache-Version: 3.0.2
```

**MISS**

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: Apache/2.4.16 (Unix) mod_auth_kerb/5.4 PHP/5.3.29
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.29
X-Drupal-Cache: MISS
Expires: Sun, 19 Nov 1978 05:00:00 GMT
Cache-Control: public, max-age=300
Content-Language: en
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Encoding: gzip
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
X-Cookie-Debug: Request cookie: _gat_UA-15166137-36=1
X-Request-URL: /org/31633421?unit=31633421
Content-Length: 11978
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Date: Wed, 24 Apr 2019 14:23:52 GMT
X-Varnish: 1900997574
Via: 1.1 varnish
Connection: keep-alive
X-Varnish-Cache: MISS
X-Varnish-Age: 0
X-Varnish-Leg: 128.87.225.158
X-Varnish-Cache-Version: 3.0.2
```

I have tried to increase the `TTL` value, remove all the cookies (including Google Analytics) but still it's behaving abruptly.

Any idea why?

**Update**

Seems like this is happening for including the following Google Tag manager JS code in my view template.

```
<script>(function(w,d,s,l,i){w[l]=w[l]||[];w[l].push({'gtm.start':
      new Date().getTime(),event:'gtm.js'});var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
      j=d.createElement(s),dl=l!='dataLayer'?'&l='+l:'';j.async=true;j.src=
      'https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id='+i+dl;f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f);
      })(window,document,'script','dataLayer','GTM-XXX');</script>
```

Comment: Why are the cache-control headers different in the two responses? Why does one response have an Expire header and the other does not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out it WAS actually a problem in the VCL configuration with the regex I was using. I had not considered the non-alpha characters of the Google Ananlytics cookie. Modified the regex to `_[_\-\.\=a-zA-Z0-9]` and everything is fun again!

Hope this helps somebody.

Answer (score 2):

My guess is that it comes from two different varnish servers based on the two response headers:

```
X-Varnish-Leg: 128.87.225.172
```

and

```
X-Varnish-Leg: 128.87.225.158
```

Comment: That's because we have two server legs and varnish is installed in both of them. As a result, the Varnish response comes from both of them based on the server load. But can it affect the HITs? I mean it might not show HIT for one or two responses, but once it gets cached, it should start showing HIT. That is not happening in my case. The hit to miss ratio is almost 4:1.

Also I noted a new thing, if I remove the Google analytics altogether, varnish works all perfect. I have created exception for GA cookies though in vcl.

Check comment below.

Comment: `set req.http.Cookie = regsuball(req.http.Cookie, "(^|;\s*)(_[_a-z]+|Drupal.visitor.name|WEBTRENDS_ID|WT_FPC|JSESSIONID|sifrFetch|sso_hide_login|ei_session_test|ei_session|has_js|BIGipServer[a-zA-Z_0-9]*)=[^;]*", "");`

Answer (score 0):

+1 for Ronald, also please consider upgrading to the latest Varnish 6 as years have passed since Varnish 3, many bugs have been fixed and improvements built. Furthermore V3 is end of life.

Comment: Yes, actually this question is for our old application which itself is on an old Drupal platform. We are upgrading that. In this new iteration, we have used Varnish 4. Quick question though, if we do plan to upgrade varnish in this new platform from 4 to 6 as you are suggesting, how much difference do you think it will have on the configuration language changes?

Comment: Moving from 4 to 6 is less disruptive than moving from 3 to 4. VCL dosn't change much from 4 to 6, you can have a look at the "upgrading VCL" section: https://docs.varnish-software.com/varnish-cache-plus/upgrading/config-41-to-60/

Comment: Thanks for this. Though still waiting for an answer of my original question. :P

Comment: Ronald answered it: if you have two caches, their caches aren't synchronized (in the open-source version)